# Sum over defined number of rows (SSMS)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I am trying to sum the `hours` column in my table over a defined number (4) of rows rather than all rows. This is for a 4-week rolling sum, but I do not want a date constraint as the weeks may not increase linearly (as shown in the example table), simply summing the previous 4 rows.

I have tried to do a row_number over partition by to define the rows, but my issue is now how to define the sum for an integer number of rows. I don't think this is the right approach.

```
select
a.week,
a.week_number,
a.name,
a.hours,
row_number() over( partition by a.week, a.name order by a.week) as partition

from my_table a
```

Here is an example of the table (assuming week 1 was 2021-01-25):

| week | week_number | name | hours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-25 | 1 | John | 25 |
| 2021-02-08 | 3 | John | 10 |
| 2021-02-15 | 4 | John | 20 |
| 2021-03-08 | 7 | John | 25 |
| 2021-03-22 | 9 | John | 20 |

So I want to sum the hours of weeks (3,4,7,9) as they are the last 4 rows, giving 75 hours total.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use window functions:

```
sum(hours) over (partition by name
                 order by week
                 rows between 3 preceding and current row
                )
```

This logic assumes that you want the sum independently for each `name`, which seems like a reasonable interpretation of the question.

Comment: `rows 3 preceding` is short for `rows between 3 preceding and current row`

Answer (score 1):

There is a great function in Transact-SQL called **lag** function.

**Lag(hours, n, 0)** will return the *hours* value for the *n*-th previous row in your table. In case there is no lag to return (e.g. first value of your table), it will return *0* (you can specify this in the third parameter of the lag function)

You could use a CTE to create rows for all 3 previous hour values in your table:

```
WITH cte_lags AS (
  SELECT 
    a.week,
    a.week_number,
    a.name,
    lag(hours, 1, 0) over( partition by a.week, a.name order by a.week) as lag_1,
    lag(hours, 2, 0) over( partition by a.week, a.name order by a.week) as lag_2,
    lag(hours, 3, 0) over( partition by a.week, a.name order by a.week) as lag_3
  FROM
    my_table a
)
```

Then you could just sum the fields to select the data you need:

```
SELECT 
  week,
  week_number,
  name,
  hours,
  hours + lag_1 + lag_2 + lag_3 AS rolling_sum
FROM
  cte_lags;
```

Comment: Though this works, I must admit that using 3 `LAG`s when you could achieve this with a single `SUM` feels a *little* over kill.